# $(window).load doesn't seem to be working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

So I've got some code that need's to be executed only when content of the website is loaded so I place it within window load, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
   //some stuff happens
});
```

Works perfectly fine in safari and chrome (I'm on mac osx 10.8), however doesn't seem to be working on firefox (19.0.2). Is there a fix or something that need's to be applied in order to make firefox work with it?

It works if I clear cache in firefox, but doesn't work any time after that.

Comment: There probably is something messing up your code. What is the version of jQuery you are using? Can you post some of your code? You need to troubleshoot the problem, not assuming right away that the problem is the `$(window).load` jQuery method...

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwtFR/) to see if it works.

Comment: @silentw I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, I think fiddle is not working in firefox as I get alert message before image finishes loading. This is so strange, there is same issue with opera as well.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid Yea, It was strange. It didn't work during development on my machine, however once I put the site on the host and it was online, everything seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try `window.onload = function(){}`

Comment: Just tried it out, still nothing, same issue appears in opera as well

Comment: Why is this answer accepted yet the OP responded that it is not working for them? Kind of confusing...

Answer (score 5):

Incase anyone else find this page from Google...

For me the following does work on Firefox:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Do something
});
```

But when the page gets cached, such as when the back button is clicked, `$(window).load()` does not get called again. See [this](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8684) for the bug report. This is expected behavior from Firefox so do not expect a fix.

2 things to fix this are either stop the browser from caching the page when hitting the back button using this code (in addition to your `$(window).load()` code):

```
window.onunload = function(){}; //This forces bfcache to not cache the page
```

Or use the other jQuery event instead of `$(window).load()`:

```
window.onpageshow = function () {
    //Do something
};
```

Comment: that "window.onpageshow" works perfectly with firefox for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you use `jQuery`. Use the jQuery event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // YOUR CODE
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this does not offer the same functionality as `$(window).load`.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it's working in all browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    alert('do something');  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Same stuff, however this one works first time I load a page, I assume it gets cached and then it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 0):

just simply do

```
my_function(){
    // some code
}
```

window.onload = my_function

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix, so I don't have to rewrite a lot of code, mostly when you use anonymous functions...

```js
// this must be at the very top
window.loaded = false;
window.addEventListener( 'load', function(){
    window.loaded = true;
});

// ...

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // add `loaded` to the events
    $(window).on('load loaded resize scroll', function(){
        // ...
    });

    // this must be at the very bottom
    if( window.loaded ){
        $(window).trigger('loaded');
        $(document).trigger('loaded');
    }
});
```